# how to sort a generic (void*) array?

Tags: c, sorting, generic-programming, void-pointers

There's an array that is passed in of type void*. I want to sort the array, but I need to be able to create a temporary value for switching parts of the array. How can I do that?

So, I am switching values using memcpy through this:

```
memcpy(temp, first, size);
memcpy(first, cur, size);
memcpy(cur, temp, size);
```

where I am trying to switch the first and cur elements. (Yes, they are pointers). Is this right? Because I am getting errors with my program although I'm not sure it's from this. (Errors as in inaccurate output.)

Comment: Read [*Modern C*](https://modernc.gforge.inria.fr/) then [this C reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c). You could want to use [qsort(3)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/qsort.3.html)

Comment: If you two variables of an unknown type, you should at least know the byte length of these variables in order to swap their values. Knowing the byte length, you can swap their values using `memcpy`. If array just contain pointers (for example, a string array is in fact an array of pointers pointing to strings), you just can swap the pointers (without doing any memcpy).

Comment: You cannot do that without knowing the size of array element.

Comment: @ssd Am I using this correctly? Because when I am sorting an array, the first two elements switch properly, but then it goes wack in that the second elements becomes a number thats not even in the array and the third element becomes 0.

Comment: Swap looks OK to me. Maybe the function calling this routine has some **index** issues. Can you post that part & the function decoration as well? And btw, these variables `temp`, `first` & `cur` need to be pointers; are they?

Comment: Did you assign space for `temp`? `void *temp = malloc(size); if (!temp) /* error */; ... free(temp);`

Comment: Yes, I do, I assign temp the space early on, and then the variables are pointers.

Comment: its a classic generic C programming problem, generic sort function! see my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your implementation is OK but in connection with your [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62787675/how-to-switch-values-in-an-array-of-unknown-type?noredirect=1#comment111035354_62787675), your function decoration should be, like;

edit: "l" is replaced by "byteLength"

```
void swap(void *a, void *b, size_t byteLength) {
    void *tmp = malloc(byteLength);

    memcpy(tmp, a, byteLength);
    memcpy(a, b, byteLength);
    memcpy(b, tmp, byteLength);

    free(tmp);
    return;
}
```

And, if you are swapping strings (that is, `(char *)` pointers);

```
void swap(void **a, void **b) {
    void *tmp;

    tmp = *a;
    *a = *b;
    *b = tmp;

    return;
}

...
...

{
    char *a = "some string";
    char *b = "some other string";
    ...
    ...

    // somewhere in the calling function
    swap(&a, &b);
}
```

Comment: Suggestion: avoid single-letter identifier `l`

Answer (score 0):

Its the heart of generic programming. if you want to sort an array of `void*` pointers (each pointer can point to whatever data type, usualy its user defined structures), you need an equality function/function pointer. lets assume that we have the structure below:

```
typedef struct
    int foo;
    ....
    ....
    
}s_ex;
```

and we are intializing an array of `s_ex` structures by allocating each struct on the heap.

```
 void* arr[];
```

And we want to pass this array of `void*` pointers to sort function, generic function that can sort any data type:

the function signature:

```
void gen_sort(void **user_array,int n, int(*fp_equality)(void*,void*));
```

the only one who knows how to compare two items is the caller (the one who build these data types)! so he needs to pass a function fp_equality that knows how to compare two items and return the result as `int` (like `strcmp`).

the algorithm of the sort is not an issue, you can decide what sort algo suits your program. i am taking bubble sort for simplicity:

```
void gen_sort(void **user_array,int n; int(*fp_equality)(void*,void*))
{
    int i, j;  
    for (i = 0; i < n-1; i++)      
      
    // Last i elements are already in place  
    for (j = 0; j < n-i-1; j++)
        if(fp_equality(arr[j],arr[j+1])>0)   /*like: (arr[j] > arr[j+1])*/    
            swap(&arr[j], &arr[j+1]);  
}  

void swap(void** lhs, void** rhs)
{
    void* temp = *lhs;
    *lhs=*rhs;
    *rhs=temp;
}
```

Comment: The swap method won't work this way. And I can't use foo[index] on an input of *array.

Comment: @sure you can use `foo[index]`. why swap wont work? why you can use foo[index]?, let me tell you something. this is the only way it will work, cos void* pointer arithmietic *(arr+offset) is imossible.